# Chrome Extension to record web pages

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

Is there a Google Chrome extension that can cache/record the webpage I've opened? And let me revisit while not connecting to internet. I don't want to use website mirroring tools since the website is huge and a lot of pages are irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

A while ago I've come across an interesting piece of software named [MailNoter](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/MailNoter.html) (written by one of the core authors of TortoiseSVN).

The core purpose is to easily send (web) content to your mailbox, so you can read it later.

[image]

The website introduces the tool best:

> MailNoter is a small tool to help gathering notes from various applications, but specifically from browsers.
>
> There are many tools and applications out there which help to keep a repository of personal notes, and even though some of them are very good at what they do, they all either use a proprietary format to store the notes (what would happen to my notes if the app isn't supported anymore and stops working on future OS versions?), only store notes as plain text, require non WYSIWYG input (e.g., Wikis), don't allow attachments, don't work if there's no network access, or are just plain ugly.
>
> So I'm keeping my notes in my email account:
>
> - open storage format
> - available from different computers and OS
> - works offline
> - usable with any email client
> - usable through a webbrowser (no need to install anything if I'm at a place where I can't just install apps)
> - easily searchable (either through the web interface (did I mention I'm using GMail?)), through desktop search engines or the email client itself
>
> And with GMail, I can add tags to my notes very easily, which makes searching them even easier.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Pocket](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/niloccemoadcdkdjlinkgdfekeahmflj), formerly known as Read It Later.

It is very nice and portable to other devices if you want to read your articles away.

Answer (score 1):

Yes [scrapbook extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gokffdfnlmampchciemmflgbckijpmlb) will do it for you very easily. As you can see in the below screen shot I'm disconnected from the Internet and can see the content of the page.

[image]

Comment: **WARNING: This extension will no longer be updated (except bug fixes)**